# Using solr with java web application in netbeans and tomcat

Tags: web-applications, netbeans, solr

I am working on a small java web application using netbeans which uses Apache Tomcat.

I got the solr running, and I can make the queries. But its running as a separate app on a different port(8983). So when I do a query to this app from my web app from java script I get the CORS error. I know that the reason of this error is the cross origin policy. So I wanted to know how can I make solr and my web app work as a complete single app using netbeans.
Also I am not allowed to change the server policy to accept request from some different domain.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using JSONP to bypass the CORS issue. See [Solr with JSONP with JQuery](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/11/solr-with-jsonp-with-jquery/) for an example of how to query Solr using JSONP.

**Update:**

Since JSONP is not an option in your scenario, the way to make them both a single app is to use [EmbeddedSolrServer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer) that is part of the SolrJ Java Client.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as I said I don't have to touch the CORS issue. Is there any way to run both modules as a single app?

Comment: Ok, thought that JSONP might be an option for you. Since it is not, I have updated my answer.